# Batch rename files by changing prefix and suffix

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-mavericks

I have a folder, say myImages, that contains a number of images. Every image is named `IMG_**.JPG`, where the `**` stand for a number. I want to rename the images to `img_**.jpg`. Is there a quick way for doing this? Or do I have to manually edit the name of each image?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zmv` in `zsh`

```
zmv -W 'IMG_*.JPG' 'img_*.jpg'
```

http://onethingwell.org/post/24608988305/zmv

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.
It is probably easiest in a script that supports `regular expressions`, such as the following `Perl` script

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @files = glob "IMG_**.JPG";
foreach my $file (@files) {
    (my $newname = $file) =~ s/IMG(.*)\.JPG/img$1.jpg/;
    rename $file, $newname;
}
```